# JCL error - "$HASP165 IBMUSERW ENDED AT SVSCJES2 - JCL ERROR CN(INTERNAL)"

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jcl, cics

I am trying to the utility DFHWS2LS to create a CICS Web service requester.

The first step mentioned in the IBM redbooks or the guides is running this in a JCL.

I face this issue on submitting the JCL.

I am doing something wrong. Can't figure out what.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

```
//IBMUSERW JOB (),'WS2LS',MSGCLASS=A,NOTIFY=&SYSUID,                
// REGION=0M                                                        
//  SET QT=''''                                                     
//         JCLLIB ORDER=(IBMUSER.SAMPLE.JCLS)                       
//JAVAPROC EXEC DFHWS2LS,REGION=0M,                                 
// PATHREF='/u',                                                    
// TMPFILE=&QT.&SYSUID.&QT                                          
//INPUT.SYSUT1 DD *                                                 
PDSLIB=//IBMUSER.SAMPLE.CPYBK                                       
REQMEM=REQCOP                                                       
RESPMEM=RESCOP                                                      
LANG=COBOL                                                          
LOGFILE=                                                            
/u/SharedProjectDirectory/MyFirstWebServiceRequester/wsbind/example.log       
MAPPING-LEVEL=3.0                                                   
CHAR-VARYING=NULL                                                   
INLINE-MAXOCCURS-LIMIT=2                                            
URI=exampleApp/example                                              
PGMINT=COMMAREA                                                     
SYNCONRETURN=YES                                                     
WSBIND=                                                             
/u/SharedProjectDirectory/MyFirstWebServiceRequester/wsbind/ES.wsbind         
WSDL=                                                               
/u/SharedProjectDirectory/MyFirstWebServiceRequester/wsdl/ES.wsdl   
/*
```

Comment: In the spool, JESYSMSG mentions "IEFC001I PROCEDURE DFHWS2LS WAS EXPANDED USING PRIVATE LIBRARY IBMUSER..."

Comment: With any error message it impossible to know what is going on. IEFC001I is just an information message. Suggest asking at work first

Comment: Thanks Bruce.

i am the only guy working on this one.
I have no experience working on this earlier and I am checking out many questions on the forums and elsewhere.

Could you suggest me some different way to access the PDS?

for sure, the access to the location of the PROC DFHWS2LS is the issue here.

I built this JCL by referring the ibm redbooks and other docs.

Comment: There is an existing web service already at work which is used for encryption of data.
I am looking to use that in an application program on mainframes.

the application needs to call the encryption service over the internet.

Using CICS Web services (CICS TS) is the right way?

Comment: Provided you're using `SDSF`, select the job with a question mark and look in the `JESMSGLG` and `JESYSMSG` `DDs` for more specific error messages.  IBM samples often require site-specific customization.  Have you talked to your Sysprog?

Comment: @cschneid - [link](http://imgur.com/a/llBy2)

This is the output of JESYSMSG.

Comment: You might want to change your [MSGLEVEL](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.ieab600/xjbmsgle.htm) to (1,1) and rerun.

Comment: Add MSGLEVEL=(1,1) doesnt help.

I am now checking the JESJCL in the spool. The DFHWS2LS is being substituted properly. But i am not able to figure out why the JCL is not running.

Comment: @cschneid - Dont know how did this happen.
But its A step ahead now..
I removed the PATHREF variable from the JCL and it executed giving me a MAXCC=8.

Now i need to figure out the errors inside the steps.

Hopefully i can take this ahead.

Here is the [link](http://imgur.com/a/mK7Jl) to the current situation.

Thanks for all the assistance till now

Answer (score 0):

This is intended as an expanded comment

```
JCLLIB ORDER=(IBMUSER.SAMPLE.JCLS)
```

is saying look for JCL procedures in IBMUSER.SAMPLE.JCLS. The message

```
IEFC001I PROCEDURE DFHWS2LS WAS EXPANDED USING PRIVATE LIBRARY IBMUSER...
```

says the JCL procedure DFHWS2LS was found in IBMUSER...

---

There is nothing in the question that indicates what the problem actually is.

```
PDSLIB=//IBMUSER.SAMPLE.CPYBK
```

is defining the PDSLIB as IBMUSER.SAMPLE.CPYBK I have no idea if this PDS exists.

There may be local site versions of these files but you would need to check with the System-Programmers where they are.

---

You need to supply more error message, hopefully then some one can help you

Comment: I copied the DFHWS2LS from DFH530.CICS.SDFHINST PDS to my own PDS 'IBMUSER.SAMPLE.JCLS' so that access issues wont occur.
----------
The JESYSMSG mentions only that 'IEFC001I PROCEDURE DFHWS2LS WAS EXPANDED USING PRIVATE LIBRARY IBMUSER.SAMPLE.JCLS'.
-----------
The PDS 'IBMUSER.SAMPLE.CPYBK' exists. -----------
I intend that to be the PDS in which the newly created copybooks must be kept. ------------

Upon submitting the JCL i get the response as mentioned in the title of this question.

Comment: $hasp165 is a generic message http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.hasa100/m001094.htm there should be something more specific

Comment: Thanks for your help till now @bruce-martin