# I am getting a $HASP165 error (JOB09746 $HASP165 KC03A081 ENDED AT SVSCJES2 - JCL ERROR CN(INTERNAL)) in my JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl

Currently working on JCL and every single time I submit, an error pops up (the one in the title). I just cannot figure out what is going on and I believe i'm overthinking it but every time that I go and take a quick break, when I come back, it does it all over again no matter what I change. I just cannot pin-point what the problem is. I thought that maybe I overlooked something and need another set of eyes. I'm quite new to JCL so i'm just trying to run a program I have in one of my pds.

Code:

```
 //KC03A081 JOB 1,SPENSER,NOTIFY=&SYSUID,MSGCLASS=H,           
 //* THIS JOB WILL COMPILE, LINK, AND GO A GIVEN PROGRAM      
 //STEP1    EXEC IGYWCLG,                                      
 // PARM.COBOL='TEST,RENT,APOST,OBJECT,NODYNAM,SIZE(2048376)'  
 //COBOL.SYSIN DD DSN=KC03A08.SOURCE.CBLWI19(CBLSJL01),DISP=SHR
 //GO.RESERVATION-MASTER DD DSN KC03A08.TRAN.IN,DISP=SHR       
 //GO.RATES-MASTER DD DSN KC03A08.TRAN.IN,DISP=SHR             
 //GO.DISCOUNT-MASTER DD DSN KC03A08.TRAN.IN,DISP=SHR          
 //GO.TAX-MASTER DD DSN KC03A08.TRAN.IN,DISP=SHR               
 //GO.CAMPBILLPRT DD DSN=KC03A08.STUDENT.PRT,                  
 //             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                       
 //             UNIT=SYSDA,                                    
 //             SPACE=(TRK,(1,1)),                             
 //             DCB=(DSORG=PS,LRECL=133,RECFM=FBA,BLKSIZE=1330)
 //
```

Solutions I have Tried:

[JCL error - "$HASP165 IBMUSERW ENDED AT SVSCJES2 - JCL ERROR CN(INTERNAL)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681692/jcl-error-hasp165-ibmuserw-ended-at-svscjes2-jcl-error-cninternal)

http://www.ibmmainframeforum.com/jcl/topic1301.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.hasa100/m001094.htm

Comment: Without the error messages it is hard to tell but...first error is line 1 - your job card is ending with a comma and so it is expecting a continuation but there is none.

Comment: Secondly - DDnames are restricted to 8 bytes (7 is better) and no special characters and should match the file name within your program. Example... for this statement "SELECT COPY-FILE ASSIGN TO ICOPY FILE STATUS IS WS-FS-ICOPY" the DDname would be ICOPY.

Comment: Thirdly - not an error but...Your DCB statement for the output file can be reduced to LRECL=133,RECFM=FBA,BLKSIZE=0. These sub---keywords are keywords in their own right nowadays.

Comment: I went ahead and made some changes to the JCL and I am still getting the error. Now you said that its hard to tell without the error messages. Do you know a way that I can navigate to those error messages exactly?

Comment: Only if you have SDSF as your spool viewer. You would apear to be a student so ask your tutor. You should be taught how to view your job output BEFORE running a job. Also, edit your question to add the revised JCL.

Comment: If you make an error on the jobcard (such as having the comma but no continuation) then none of the statements on the jobcard are processed. This means that the system does not parse the MSGCLASS parameter and so does not have anywhere to send the job log with more details of the JCL errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IGYWCLG is an IBM supplied cataloged procedure for compiling and linking a COBOL program.  It consists of three steps:

- COMPILE
- LinkEdit
- GO

Looks like the main issues are in the overrides and some other JCL issues.  In order here

`//KC03A081 JOB 1,SPENSER,NOTIFY=&SYSUID,MSGCLASS=H,`
The JOB card is in error.  It ends with a , but there is no continuation.  This is a JCL Error that will terminate job processing.

```
 //* THIS JOB WILL COMPILE, LINK, AND GO A GIVEN PROGRAM      
 //STEP1    EXEC IGYWCLG,                                     
 // PARM.COBOL='TEST,RENT,APOST,OBJECT,NODYNAM,SIZE(2048376)'
```

This executes the Proc IGYWCLG to compile, link and go the following COBOL program.

`//COBOL.SYSIN DD DSN=KC03A08.SOURCE.CBLWI19(CBLSJL01),DISP=SHR`

The above statement doesn't have any apparent errors.

The following statements are overrides to the `GO` step in the proc.  It appears these references to files used in the compiled COBOL program.

Several recurring problems exist in this area.  The statement is listed followed by the comments.

`//GO.RESERVATION-MASTER DD DSN KC03A08.TRAN.IN,DISP=SHR`

The DDName `RESERVATION-MASTER` is not a valid DDName.  DDNames are up to 8 characters in length.  In the `DATA DIVISION` `FILE CONTROL` area of the COBOL program there is an `FD` entry which should match the DDName.  It looks like you are using the `WORKING-STORAGE` references for the record formats rather than the name in the `FILE CONTROL`.

Also, you need DSN=datasetname,DISP=SHR.  you are missing the equals sign between `DSN` and the name.

```
 //GO.RATES-MASTER DD DSN KC03A08.TRAN.IN,DISP=SHR            
 //GO.DISCOUNT-MASTER DD DSN KC03A08.TRAN.IN,DISP=SHR          
 //GO.TAX-MASTER DD DSN KC03A08.TRAN.IN,DISP=SHR
```

```
 //GO.CAMPBILLPRT DD DSN=KC03A08.STUDENT.PRT,                  
 //             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                       
 //             UNIT=SYSDA,                                    
 //             SPACE=(TRK,(1,1)),                             
 //             DCB=(DSORG=PS,LRECL=133,RECFM=FBA,BLKSIZE=1330)
 //
```